# Adding Route and Perameter in Form action in html in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, forms

I am unable to get this, My Route is as under;

```
Route::patch('/info/{iplive}', ['as' => 'info', 'uses' => 'InfoController@index']);
```

and Here is My Form,

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=>'info/', 'id'=> 'lookup', 'class' => 'user_form','method'=>'PATCH']) !!}
                    <div class="row center-block">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 center-block">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" id="lookup" name="lookup" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for Address">
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Lookup</button>
                                    </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            <!--</form> -->
            {!! Form::close() !!}
```

I am in efforts to use a url like, [link](http://example.com/info/submited_ip) but unable to get it done :(

Comment: When opening the form, the url is just `info/`, but shouldn't there be something that would match the `{iplive}`

Comment: Hi Mikel, I have confimred this, I have IP information in db but its not adding /$ipaddress (submited ip address) in the end  of URL

Comment: I understand. And you have to add the `$ipaddress` to your form url, like this `{!! Form::open(['url'=>'info/'.$ipaddress, 'id'=> 'lookup', 'class' => 'user_form','method'=>'PATCH']) !!}`

Comment: Unable to send all code :( but getting this error Undefined variable: ipaddress (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\www\iplive\local\resources\views\layouts\master.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\www\iplive\local\resources\views\layouts\master.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

your route expects a paramater to be filled in,
try something like this

```
  {!! Form::open(['method' => 'PATCH', , 'id'=> 'lookup', 'class' => 'user_form', 'route' => [ 'info' , $your_iplive_variable]]) !!}
```

where $your_iplive_variable should be the paramater you wish to fill in.

Comment: Hi, I want to fill the value of provided in this Form Textbox, but unable to pick the right method.
<input type="text" id="lookup" name="lookup" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for Address">